# Apply a vendor payment to an expense report in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Is it possible to apply a vendor payment to an expense report in SuiteScript?  In the UI, you can click '**Make a Payment**' on the expense report, which suggested to me that you could use *record.transform* to transform an expense report to a vendor payment, but the documentation doesn't show that as an available transformation.

So I tried simply creating the vendor payment, and then adding the expense report to the '**Apply**' sublist, but that only results in the, ***"... you are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist.***" error.

I have tried various methods for simply adding the expense report to the '**Apply**' sublist, such as:

```
var rec = record.create({type: 'vendorpayment'});
rec.insertLine({sublistId: 'apply', line: 0});
rec.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'apply', fieldId: 'amount', value: "200.00"});
// More setting of the line values
rec.commitLine({sublistId: 'apply'});
```

...but they all seem to result in the static sublist error, which seems to suggest you can't apply a payment to an expense report that way. I've tried searching online, but haven't found an answer. Is it possible to apply a vendor payment to an expense report in SuiteScript? And if so, how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

While bknights code is the correct code for tranforming transaction/record, expense report cannot be tranformed to a vendor payment via script. The type of transformation is not listed as supported transformation type, it will just throw an error "INVALID_RCRD_TRANSFRM".

If I am going to create a payment for an expense report it will be like the code below. On your sample code, you missed setting the isDynamic to true and set the entity with the default value (which is the employee). Setting isDynamic and defaultValues will return a record object with unpaid expense report for the employee, all you need to do it just iterate the apply sublist.

```
    var objRecord = record.create({
        type: 'vendorpayment', 
        isDynamic: true,
        defaultValues: {
            entity: idEmployee
        } 
    });
    //rest of the code goes after this line
```

Comment: You're awesome man, thanks!  I actually had isDynamic set to true in my project's code, but I wasn't setting the entity as a defaultValue.  So that was the problem.  After that, it worked just as you described.  Meaning, I only need to iterate through the apply items.  Thanks again.  (I banged my head for a couple hours on this one. )

Comment: My answer is actually from working code. 'vendorbill' works as the fromType for creating an expense reimbursement.

Comment: i tried running it on debugger it keeps on throwing INVALID_RCRD_TRANSFRM. I would reference SuiteAnswer Id: 45156 to check all possible tranformation. There's no supported tranformation if the fromType is expense report. employee can be tranformed to expensereport. other than that I couldn't see anything.

Comment: I also don't see the logic of "creating an expense report from a vendorbill". Vendor Bill and Expense report are somewhat simillar and different. They are both used as AP transactions but they are used for different entity type.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a bill payment in the UI you will see that the available targets for the payment are pre-created.

You cannot add new lines but have to loop through the available 'apply' lines and find the one that matches your expense report.

BTW it's better to create the payment like:

```
var vp = record.transform({fromType:'vendorbill', fromId:expReportInternalId, toType:'vendorpayment'});
//then you can loop through the apply lines to find the appropriate doc line:
for(var i = 0; i< vp.getLineCount({sublistId:'apply'}); i++){
    if(fromId:expReportInternalId == vp.getSublistValue({sublistId:'apply', fieldId:'doc', line:i})){
        vp.setSublistValue({sublistId:'apply', fieldId:'apply', line:i, value:true});
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I actually tried transforming the record myself before posting the question, but I wasn't trying to transform a vendorbill to a vendorpayment, but instead an expensereport to a vendorpayment. And that is a transformation NS doesn't allow.  vVinceth actually provided me with the problem.  Turned out I wasn't setting 'entity' as the defaultValue.  Once I did that, the 'Apply' tab had the expense report as you described.  Thanks again

Comment: Actually using 'vendorbill' for the fromType but the expense report's internal id works to create the vendor payment for an employee reimbursement.